# How to create a nodejs HTTP server with an existing TLS client socket?

Tags: node.js, ssl, tls1.2

I have a nodejs TLS client socket on my laptop, connected to a TLS server socket on a different computer (server). The server cannot connect to my laptop. The laptop needs to initiate the connection.

Now I want the server to make requests to my laptop. The idea is to reuse the HTTP protocol. Is there a way to create a HTTP server using the existing TLS client socket?

This way, the server machine can make a HTTP request, and the client TLS receives it, and the HTTP server would parse it? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a TCP socket open between laptop and server, you can send data either way over that socket.  So, if the server wants to send some query to the laptop, it can do so just fine.   You will have to invent your own protocol on top of TCP to do that, but it could be as simple as a text/line based protocol if you want.

Or, instead of making a plain TCP connection, you can make a webSocket or socket.io connection from the laptop to the server (instead of the plain TCP connection) and then either side can send messages either way and the protocol part is already taken care of.  If you use socket.io, it will automatically reconnect if the connection is interrupted too.

There is no simple way to attach an HTTP server to an existing TCP socket and it would be fraught with difficulties too because an HTTP connection is generally not a continuous connection over which you send many separate requests (advanced versions of http can do that, but I doubt you want to get into implementing all that logic on both ends).  You could use the HTTP protocol over your existing TCP socket, but that would probably be substantially more work to implement than just use the webSocket/socket.io idea above.

Comment: But the goal here is avoid implementing my own protocol between both sides of the socket. The idea is to use the nodejs http agent to take care of the HTTP formatting and validation of the request.

Comment: @Mr.Goferito - So then use socket.io as I recommended.  It does all the protocol stuff for you.  You send messages with data either way which is even easier than http.  And,, as I said, there's no simple way to hook a lasting http server that you can send many requests over into an existing socket.  You're essentially going to have to tunnel http over your socket. That's  a mess. A socket.io connection would take me less than 15 minutes to implement.  You will have to install socket.io on both ends and see how you set a connection up and send messages, but way easier than the alternatives IMO.

Comment: I already have a working TLS connection, and I can already send text data both ways. I just wanted to avoid the part of creating my own protocol.

Comment: Also, in my humble attempts, my idea was to create a http server, and configure it somehow to listen on the existing socket. Not just throwing HTTP chunks through the socket.

Comment: Well, if you change the TLS socket to a socket.io socket, then you won't have to invent your own protocol as socket.io has already done that for you.  socket.io is based on webSocket which is specifically built for sending bi-directional messages over a long lasting connection using an existing message-based protocol.  It is built for exactly what you are trying to do.  I suggest using it.  Why are you avoiding using a mechanism and libraries specifically built for what you are doing?

Comment: @Mr.Goferito - Did this answer your question?